# Enter USA on B1 to visit grad school

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, f1-visas

I’ve obtained F1 visa to study in DC starting August 2018. Can I make a short visit (10 days) in May to see my school in DC? I already have a B1/B2 visa!

Comment: You will probably enter on B2 (personal visitor) instead of B1 (business visitor)

Answer (score 0):

Yes though in most cases you would have to exit and re-enter on your F1 visa prior to beginning school.

Comment: Doesn't **have** to, they can do a change of status however it is an unnecessarily long process changing status.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this, but it is probably not worth it.

Since you have a visa you can go, and you can either apply for a change of status (for a hefty fee) when you start your educational program, or reenter the US on the F-1.

---

Outdated:

Since you've already got your I-20, you have likely already made your mind anyways. It takes some time (and money) to apply for a B-1 visa, and you can enter the U.S. usually 30 days before the start of your program. I'd recommend that you go in July and have plenty of time to "visit your school" :-)

Comment: OP already has a B-1/B-2 visa.

Comment: @phoog didn't see that.